# google play sigin sdk for unity works on build but not production

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-games

i have included google play sigin inside my unity app and it has very strange behaviors,
when i build the app directly from unity to a mobile device it works but on production it just logs in one time then it stops, it shows the loading icon for one second and it stops.

things i have tried:
on the configuration first i created a google cloud credentials and gave it my game bundle id and keystore SHA
then in google play console i added the credential
then i unity i copied the resource i added it in the setup with Auth ID and added my keystore

on one post i found they refered to using App signing key certificate instead of Upload key certificate so i updated the SHA from google cloud, this worked for a while then i uninstalled the app and installed it from google play store then the same thing happen again.

additional information:
Integrity API responses off
Releases signed by Google Play
play games service: published
Enable anti-piracy turned off

please i really really need help with this, my boss will legit fire me if this project isn't published by the end of this week so any help is much appreciated.